# Can't change WebStorm window font size (not code font size)

Tags: user-interface, webstorm

If I go to WebStorm (2016 version) `Settings | Editor | Colors and Fonts | Font`, then I cant change the size.

I've attached a picture.

[image]

What do I need to so WebStorm will let me change the size ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Settings | Appearance & Behavior |  Appearance, Override default fonts by`

Then select which font you want to use, all your menu fonts shall then change

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Predefined editor style scheme is not editable - you need to press **Save As** to copy a scheme and then edit this custom scheme. See Help:

> Click this button to save the currently selected Colors & Fonts
>   settings as a new scheme. After saving, the scheme settings become
>   editable.

But note that **Settings | Editor | Colors and Fonts | Font** only affects editor font settings; to change the font size in dialogs/tool windows/etc., you need changing IDE font in **Settings | Appearance & Behavior |  Appearance**, **Override default fonts by**

Comment: Thanks. But it only changes the code font . How do I change other windows font size. Like Project window

Comment: I answered _your_ question - you had problems changing font in `Settings | Editor | Colors and Fonts | Font`, didn't you?